# Vitest Testing with vi mock didn't throw expected result

Tags: typescript, vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs3, vitest

So I have been writing some test files for my vue 3 component with Typescript and I have been stucked using vi.mock from vitest to mock the axios error.

Here is my sample unit test

> login.spec.ts

```
import { describe, it, expect, vi, beforeAll } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import loginVue from '../app/auth/login.page.vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { router } from '@/plugins/vue-router'

beforeAll(() => {
  const app = createApp({})
  app.use(createPinia())
})

const mountLogin = () => {
  const wrapper = mount(loginVue, {
    global: {
      plugins: [router],
      stubs: ['Icon', 'RouterLink']
    },
    attachTo: document.body
  })
  return { wrapper, router }
}

describe('Login Page', () => {
    
  it('Failed Login', async () => {
    vi.mock('@/stores/newAuth', () => ({
      useNewAuthStore: () => ({
        login: vi.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error('Invalid'))
      })
    }))

    const { wrapper } = mountLogin()
    const form = wrapper.find('form')
    await form.trigger('submit')
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()

    // console.log(wrapper.html())

    expect(wrapper.findComponent({ name: 'ErrorNotif' }).exists()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

And in my login page, there is a function that utilize pinia like this

> login.page.vue

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
  try {
    loadingStore.showLoading()
    await auth.login(loginData.value)
    router.push('/')
    loadingStore.hideLoading()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    errorLogin.value = true
    loadingStore.hideLoading()
  }
}
```

I've been trying to directly throw an error in my login method like this

```
vi.mock('@/stores/newAuth', () => ({
    useNewAuthStore: () => ({
      login: async (payload) => {
        throw new Error('Invalid');
      }
    })
  }))
```

But it's no use as it still didn't reach the catch statement in my handleLogin function in the login page. I tried to throw the AxiosError but it didn't work as well.

Any idea or scenario so that I can simulate the catch statement when the login is throwing an error in my unit test??

Note: There are some unit tests in my login.spec.ts like `vi.fn().mockResolveValue(true)` and all, and they worked fine